# Induction proof involving prime factor and binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, induction, combinations

The question in my book is:

> Use induction on $r$ to prove that if $p$ is a prime integer, then $p$ is a factor $\binom{p}{r}$ for $r=1, 2, . . . , p-1$.

I'm not really sure how to go about proving this statement using induction. Can I not simply do the following:

Expanding the factorials, we see

$\binom{p}{r}=\frac{p!}{(p-r)!(r)!}=\frac{p(p-1)(p-2) . . . (2)(1)}{(p-r)(p-r-1)...(2)(1)(r)(r-1)...(2)(1)}.$

Let $r$ be a positive integer less than $p$. It is given that $p$ is prime, so $p$ cannot be canceled. We know that $\binom{p}{r}$ is a positive integer (from an earlier exercise), so $p$ must be a factor of $\binom{p}{r}$.

If so, induction seems unnecessary. But I assume my instructor would still want me to use induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is true for $r=1$, since $\binom{p}{1}=p$. We now do the  induction step.

Suppose that $p$ divides $\binom{p}{r}$. We show that if $r+1\lt p$ then $p$ divides $\binom{p}{r+1}$.

Note that $\binom{p}{r+1}=\frac{p!}{(r+1)!(p-r-1)!}=\frac{p-r}{r+1}\binom{p}{r}$. Thus 
$$(r+1)\binom{p}{r+1}=(p-r)\binom{p}{r}.$$
By the induction hypothesis, $p$ divides the right-hand side, so it divides the left-hand side. Since $r+1\lt p$, $p$ does not divide $r+1$. So $p$ must divide $\binom{p}{r+1}$.

**Remark:** I agree, induction is certainly not necessary.